# how to set default values for attributes in xml using DTD?

Tags: xml, dtd, xmlstarlet

How do i set default values for attributes in xml. Consider below test.xml. An attribute 'gender' with default value 'male' has been defined for element 'to'. I am however unable to retrieve it using xmlstarlet. Am i doing something wrong? Please help.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE message [
  <!ELEMENT message (to,from,subject,text)>
  <!ELEMENT to       (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT from     (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT subject  (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT text     (#PCDATA)>
  <!ATTLIST to gender CDATA "male">
]>

<message>
  <to>Dave</to>
  <from>Susan</from>
  <subject>Reminder</subject>
  <text>Dont forget to buy milk on the way home.</text>
</message>
```

xmlstarlet cmd: (doesnt print anything to stdout)

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "//message/to" -v "@gender" -n test.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration of the `gender` attribute with the default value is fine. It must be something with the `sel` command of xmlstartlet. Either that or how you're trying to use it. I don't know much about xmlstarlet though. You can use XSLT to verify the default value:

**XML Input** (test.xml)

```
<!DOCTYPE message [
<!ELEMENT message (to,from,subject,text)>
<!ELEMENT to       (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT from     (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT subject  (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT text     (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST to gender CDATA "male">
]>
<message>
  <to>Dave</to>
  <from>Susan</from>
  <subject>Reminder</subject>
  <text>Dont forget to buy milk on the way home.</text>
</message>
```

**XSLT 1.0** (test.xsl)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:value-of select="to/@gender"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Command Line and Output** (xmlstarlet on Windows)

```
C:\apps\xmlstarlet-1.4.2>xml tr test.xsl test.xml
male
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, XMLStarlet is very picky about the default namespace. If the document has it declared (xmlns=), you have to declare it for XMLStarlet too, and prefix the elements with the name you have chosen. 
[See](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05s01.html) this

See [User guide](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/xmlstarlet.txt).
Try this:

```
xml sel -T -t -m "/message/to" -v "@gender" -n test.xml
```

Refer [this](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html)

Comment: I donot want the attribute value to be fixed. Any attribute value can be specified, if its not however, the xmlstarlet cmd mentioned in my question should return the default value of the attribute defined using ATTLIST.

Comment: Ok. for default attr, your code seems to be great, post the full code

Comment: the full code ? I was hoping xmlstarlet will parse the xml and get me the default value for the  gender attribute, which it doesn't.

Comment: `xmlstarlet` sel should be `xml sel`?

Comment: nope, xmlstarlet is a cmdline utility for querying,editing,validating xml files.

http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php

Comment: xml sel -T -t -m "//message/to" -v "@gender" -n test.xml
.....
No command 'xml' found, did you mean:...

Comment: `xml` is the executable the source tarball builds by default, but all 3rd party packagers rename it to `xmlstarlet`

Answer (score 0):

xmlstarlet's `sel` command doesn't have any way to get default attributes (a bug or missing feature, at least). You can work around it by using `tr` as in @DanielHaley's solution:

```
# bash allows a more concise solution than cmd.exe
xmlstarlet tr <(xmlstarlet sel -C -T -t -v /message/to/@gender) test.xml
```

Or run it through `c14n` to get default attribute values first:

```
xmlstarlet c14n test.xml | xmlstarlet sel -T -t -v /message/to/@gender
```

The `c14n` expands attribute starting from version 1.0.3. `xmllint --dtdattr` can work instead.

Comment: i get a parser error when i try: `xmlstarlet tr <(xmlstarlet -C -T -t -v /message/to/@gender) test.xml`

_/dev/fd/63:1: parser error : Document is empty_

Comment: Also, canonicalizing test.xml does get the default attributes :(, so running through c14n isnt helping

Comment: below cmds worked for me, however i am unable to do it concisely in a single cmd. i'll love to know a way to do this in a single cmd. 

`xmlstarlet sel -C -T -t -v /message/to/@gender test.xml > test.xsl`
`xmlstarlet tr test.xsl test.xml`

Comment: @KaushikLingerkar: I missed the `sel` in the `<(xmlstarlet...)` call.

Comment: `xmllint --c14n11 test.xml | xmlstarlet sel ...` also seems to work